# Erlang starting a process

Tags: erlang

I have been doing Erlang a bit but I might always get tricked out by this.

A supervisor can start a worker using start_link in a sup file.
A process can be started using {ok, _} = file:start_link() anywhere else as well.
Which way and when/why would I choose to do one over that other?

Answer (score 2):

Out of the two ways of starting a process - using a supervisor or calling a function to start the process directly - in most cases the preferred way is to use supervisors. Supervisors provide more functionality and more control over the started process. Functionality like automatic restart of a process which died unexpectedly. Supervisors are highly configurable as described [in the documentation](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/supervisor.html).

On the other hand, if you just start a process from the code directly, you either have no control or visibility over the started process, or you need to implement at least part of supervisor functionality manually.

Having said that, every rule has exceptions, and there are cases when starting process explicitly from the code is the better option. But to use a supervisor is a reasonable default.

Additional note: contrary to what the other answer suggests, using start_link and other linking functions with a supervisor is perfectly safe. Actually it is required, as the documentation states "The start function must create and link to the child process". Supervisors use links to track processes they start.

Answer (score 1):

> A supervisor is responsible for starting, stopping, and monitoring its
> child processes. The basic idea of a supervisor is that it is to keep
> its child processes alive by restarting them when necessary.
>
> Which child processes to start and monitor is specified by a list of
> child specifications.
> https://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/sup_princ.html#supervision-principles

Just because a process starts a second process does not mean the first process is a supervisor.  If the second process dies, the first process does not automatically restart the second process.  If two processes are linked, and one dies, then the other one dies as well.  You don't want a supervisor to die when one of its child processes dies.